# Foggy images detection

Tags: python, image, feature-detection

experts

I am doing a project about analysing the green trends of the trees.
In term of initial processing, I've got intensity value for the whole 500 images and decided the threshold for selecting good images from the datasets. It's around from 60 to 122, and I named the range as good images.

However, the tricky issue was that some of the foggy images were also in that range. The intensity of good images is from 90 to 120, some of the foggy images have the same intensity value compared to the good one.
[the intensity of iamges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwttw.png)

So far, it's the code for getting the intensity of one image and the average of the intensity for 500 images

```
  im = Image.open('IMAG0087.JPG')
  im_grey = im.convert('LA')
  width,height = im.size

  total=0
  for i in range(0,width):
     for j in range(0,height):
     total += im.getpixel((i,j))[0]

  mean = total / (width * height)
  print mean
```

Getting the average of the intensity for 500 images:

```
  results = []
  for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk("/Users/Terrynightbleach/Desktop/Dataset-Tree/No2_Fraser_Gully/"):
   for filename in [f for f in filenames if f.endswith('.JPG')]:
   img = cv2.imread(filename)
   avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis=0)
   avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
   results.append(sum(avg_color/3))
   np_results = np.array(results)
   plt.hist(np_results,bins=100)
   plt.show()
```

Are there any other values that I am supposed to use in order to discard those foggy images out from the datasets? And how should I achieve it by python? That would be really helpful if you could show the code.
Thank you so much!!!!!

Comment: Greetings, valiant knight. If I understand correctly, the problem is to determine which image has the most green? If so, why not compute the score `green_intensity / total_intensity`?

Comment: No lords here. Just commoners. *And how should I achieve it by python?* By using your keyboard to write the code. *really helpful if you could show the code* We're not a code writing service. No *plz give me teh codez* here.

Comment: Hi Mateen, getting the green trend of the trees is my next step of the project. Now, I'm struggling with the foggy images. I just have no ideas about which values should I use to discard the foggy images out from the dataset.

Comment: Hi Ken, Actually I 've almost done the first part of the project. I know there is no such code writing service here. I just need some hints that I can discard the foggy pictures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can see your foggy images have very low horizontal variance. Therefore you could compute average horizontal variance for each image. Here's a quick example:

```
import Image 
import glob

def slow_horizontal_variance(im):
    '''Return average variance of horizontal lines of a grayscale image'''
    width, height = im.size
    if not width or not height: return 0
    vars = []
    pix = im.load()
    for y in range(height):
        row = [pix[x,y] for x in range(width)]
        mean = sum(row)/width
        variance = sum([(x-mean)**2 for x in row])/width
        vars.append(variance)
    return sum(vars)/height

for fn in glob.glob('*.png'):
    im = Image.open(fn).convert('L')
    var = slow_horizontal_variance(im)
    fog = var < 200    # FOG THRESHOLD
    print ('%5.0f - %5s - %s' % (var, fog and 'FOGGY' or 'SHARP', fn))
```

Output:

```
  104 - FOGGY - 00.png
  298 - SHARP - 01.png
  597 - SHARP - 02.png
  130 - FOGGY - 03.png
```

The images:

00.png

[image: 00.png foggy landscape]

01.png

[image: 01.png landscape]

02.png

[image: 02.png landscape]

03.png

[image: 03.png foggy landscape]

---

So using `numpy`, instead of your code:

```
avg_color_per_row = numpy.average(img, axis=0)
avg_color = numpy.average(avg_color_per_row, axis=0)
```

You would have something like:

```
intensity_variance_per_row = numpy.var(img, axis=0)
avg_variance = numpy.average(intensity_variance_per_row, axis=0)
fog = avg_variance  < 200    # FOG THRESHOLD
print ('%5.0f - %5s - %s' % (avg_variance, fog and 'FOGGY' or 'SHARP', filename))
```

(Unfortunately, I'm too lazy to install numpy on this machine, so I cannot confirm it works as well as my slow code above. If it doesn't, you might need to change `numpy.var(img, axis=0)` to `numpy.var(img, axis=1)`.)

Comment: Hi Andriy, Thanks a lot. just got a question. What does the horizontal variance represent? Can I understand on this way? like it means the horizontal variance of the intensity of image?  And I also got a couple of  extremely foggy images from the datasets, the average of the intensity for those are around 92.

Comment: @TerryLiu, I updated the answer translating my slow solution to something more like your own code. Is that more clear to you? Variance of intensity in a row is how much colors differ in that row. Forest has high variance because leaves (high intensity) are mixed with shades (low intensity). Fog, on the other hand, has roughly similar intensity over any row, so variance of intensity in those rows will be low.

Comment: it is quite useful, and it works perfectly. The speed of process increases a lot, but it would be perfect if it could detect the images by order of the images. Well, I will figure it out then. Thank you so much, appreciate your help.

Comment: Actually, I've done some reading stuff about the foggy images detection. Some of them, like "Detecting Foggy Images and Estimating the Haze Degree Factor". They use 'Haze Degree Estimation Function' to detect and decide if pictures are foggy. But some formulas in that article are quite hard to understand and no ideas about how to convert it to the python code. But, as you mentioned, Variance of intensity is an obvious value to distinguish the foggy images from the datasets, it is also really useful to help me to discard some images, which are totally dark.

Comment: @TerryLiu, I just looked at the values: as you can see above, the highest horizontal variance for a foggy landscape was 130, the lowest for clear landscape was 298. So to classify all images correctly, my threshold just had to be between 130 and 298, so I chose 200. You should just pick a threshold that works best for you. Of course, you can write a script that will choose an optimal threshold for you based on a training set. It's a good idea.

Comment: @ Andriy Makukha, hey my lord, are you still floating around StackOverflow? I still have the same question that needs to be validated. It's about the threshold. My supervisors just asked me how did you know this threshold was correct.  He asked me to validate this threshold, like the accuracy... It sounds like some machine learning techniques. Would it be ok you could give me some hints about it? Really appreciate...